# Reduce number of shared_ptrs in persistent data structure

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm faced with a design choice for a singly linked list class. The rough idea is this:

```
template<typename T>
class List {
public:
    ...

private:
    struct Node {
        std::shared_ptr<const T> value;
        std::shared_ptr<const Node> next;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<const Node> node_;
};
```

Yes I know there are a lot of `shared_ptr`s wandering around, but that's because `List` is a functional persistent data structure that needs as much structural sharing as possible. In this implementation, for example, reversing a list does not require copying any elements, and multiple lists can share a common sub-list (by pointing to a same `shared_ptr` tail).

That being said, I still feel there are perhaps too many `shared_ptr`s. Is there anyway to reduce the number of `shared_ptr`s used while still enabling structural sharing? Something like combining the two `shared_ptr`s inside a `Node` to reduce the overhead of control blocks... I don't know, maybe there isn't a way, or maybe there is. Any idea is welcome, even about redesigning the `List` class altogether.

Comment: Can't a Node encapsulate a T?

Comment: @RichardHodges Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why not a plain `T` member?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because `List` is an immutable data structure, and any modification on it is non-destructive and will return a whole new `List`. If I use plain `T` members, then for every new list I'll need to copy every elements from the old list. If I use a `shared_ptr<const T>` instead, the new list and the original one can share the same `T`s (only the `shared_ptr`s are copied).

Comment: @ZizhengTai But you could write a simple list view type that references, say, an `std::forward_list`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Then given such a list (view), how can I create a new list (view) that equals the original list with the 2nd element removed? I don't think `std::forward_list` can do that without copying every element involved.

Comment: You can use containers of `std::reference_wrapper` to create multiple "views" of a container without modifying the original and without copying the elements.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But that's asymptotically the same. A functional data structure can do the thing I mentioned in the comment above in O(1) time, but even using `std::reference_wrapper` would still take O(n) time.

Comment: @ZizhengTai: a list storing `T` *can* contain `T=shared_ptr<U>`, but you can't do this the other way around. Therefore, storing `T` is more generic.

Comment: @lorro Ah, good point. For types like `List<int>` using plain `T` would be much better, and I can probably do something like `using SharedList<T> = List<std::shared_ptr<T>>;` for expensive `T`s.

Answer (score 2):

You want to share data without structure (the reverse case).

You want to share structure.

Both require shared pointers.  However, if you want to reduce control block overhead, this can be done, so long as you entangle lifetimes.

You can make the T's lifetime tied to its node.  The reversed node then needs to also make the original node persist.  This can cause structure to outlive its needs, but makes the pure-forward case less expensive.

Make the pointer-to-T a raw pointer.

Create a combined struct with a T and a Node in it.

Use `make_shared` to create it.

Now make the pointer-to-T point at the T in the combined struct.

Next, use the aliasing ctor to create a shared ptr to the Node sharing the control block of the combined struct.

To reverse, create a helper struct with a Node and a shared ptr to Node.  Make shared the helper.  Point the shared node ptr to the forward node, the T ptr to the T ptr in the forward node, and then use the aliasing ctor of shared ptr to get a shared ptr to Node.

I do not think this is worth it.